# single category widget with conditional terms

Tags: categories, widgets

iam working on my first wp theme and iam new to php and wordpress.
i need to create a single category widget that displays 
at least five posts from specific category.
inside this post loop i need a conditional function
to make the first post different from the rest.
to be clear iam [using a plugin that gives me all the needed option](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-posts/screenshots/)
except conditional function that makes the first post different from the others.
is there any one could help me By editing the plugin file to add this conditional function .
or showing me the entire code from scratch.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the first post different you could add a post counter and change the output on the first loop.

```
$counter = 0
while ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) {
$cat_posts->the_post();
    $counter++;

 if ( $counter == 0 ) {

 // Out put the different loop

}

  //Normal loop output
```

Comment: thanx Chris that's exactly what I meant .i tested it and works for me

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much code to this plugin, main output is done by [pretty straightforward loop](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/category-posts/tags/3.3/cat-posts.php#L81).

Unfortunately plugin gives no way to control styling of individual items so you will have to either:

- fork it and edit to output class for styling for first item alone
- try to make use of CSS for styling of existing markup (`:first-child` if I am not mistaken)

Comment: thanks Rarst . but i wanted it in the loop because iam going to display just the thumb in the first post..